# BigQuery partitioned tables: What's the shortest way to specify a month?

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, google-bigquery

Wondering what's the shortest way to specify a month when querying partitioned tables.

`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC` to the month looks tempting, but doesn't seem to work as a partition filter:

```
SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(datehour, month) = '2018-04-01'

Cannot query over table 'fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018' without a filter that can be used for partition elimination
```

`BETWEEN` dates looks tempting too, but requires knowing how many days each month has:

```
SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-31'

Could not cast literal "2018-04-31" to type DATE at [3:47]
```

`DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(month), day` works, but requires typing the date twice and is lengthy to type:

```
SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE DATE(datehour) 
  BETWEEN '2018-04-01' 
  AND DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2018-04-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 

15746003449
```

How would you improve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would just do:

```
SELECT SUM(views) as views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE hour >= date '2018-04-01' AND hour < date '2018-05-01';
```

You can put the date constants in a CTE:

```
with params as (
      select date '2018-04-01' as dte
     )
select sum(views) as views
from params cross join
     `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
where hour >= params.dte AND hour < date_add(params.dte, interval 1 month)
```

Comment: This works! But what I don't like is having to type the date twice, adjusting the second one to add a month manually.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: while further experimenting, this is my best solution:

```
SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(DATE(datehour), month) = '2018-04-01'
```

That's essentially the first attempt in the question, plus casting the timestamp to DATE, and then applying `DATE_TRUNC`.

Leaving the other options I tried below, as they could be useful for other situations.

---

One option is to use WITH to define a variable, thus typing the month only once:

```
WITH month AS (SELECT DATE('2018-04-01') m), 
  full_month AS (SELECT m AS s, DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(m, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS e FROM month)

SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE DATE(datehour) 
  BETWEEN (SELECT s FROM full_month) AND (SELECT e FROM full_month)
```

Similarly, you could define SQL UDF functions:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION month() AS (DATE('2018-04-01'));
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION month_end() AS (DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(month(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY));

SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2018`
WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN month() AND month_end()
```

For both options, BigQuery can identify and optimize scanning only the required partitions.